# How it is possible to export PowerPoint slides into a PDF from a selection of sections?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have split my PowerPoint slides into several sections. Now I want to export my slides into a PDF. How can I export only a selection of sections into the PDF?

I know the feature of creating custom shows and export PDF according to a custom show. But is it also possible for sections?

If possible, I want to avoid VBA scripting.

Comment: A selection of sections as in multiple sections into one PDF file?

Comment: My target is to export one single PDF file, and before chose individually the sections, which will be included in this PDF.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're converting to PDF.

But first, go into Slide Sorter view and select the slides you want to save as PDF or print to PDF.

Then in the Print dialog or the Save As dialog, there are options for printing/saving the currently selected slides.

Comment: As you write, I must "select the slides". This is exactly what I do NOT want to do, as I must select single slides instead of sections. I couldn't find any options in this view to select sections. If I only have some few slides, this may be useful, but in my case I have much more slides (which are separated into sections).